# using defined environmental variable in with block for github actions

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to figure out how to reference a global scoped environmental variable for input in to an action like so:

```yaml
name: validate
on: pull_request

env:
  CONFIG_PATH: configuration/conf.json

jobs:

  upload_config:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: create config
        shell: bash -l {0}
        run: |
          mkdir `dirname ${CONFIG_PATH}`
          echo "some config" > ${CONFIG_PATH}

      - name: upload config
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: config
          path: ${{ CONFIG_PATH }}
```

However I am getting an invalid yaml error stating there is an "Unrecognized named-value: 'CONFIG_PATH'". If I try referencing the environmental variable like so:

```yaml
path: ${CONFIG_PATH}
```

I get a "Path does not exist ${CONFIG_PATH}" error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find a clear example of it in the docs but you need to use the [env context](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#env-context) for this like so:

```yaml
path: ${{ env.CONFIG_PATH }}
```